# Do I have to add the primary key of model as hidden file in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering if there's a proper way to edit the form without add the primary key of the model in the view as hidden field as this makes my app vulnerable

here's an example of what I am saying:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditOrder", "Orders", ajaxOptions, new { id = "edit-order-form" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.OrderLineID)
}
```

and here's the inspection of page:

[image: Page Inspection]

In this way the user can edit the id,
so i am just wondering if there's another way to do this

Comment: Yes. If your `EditOrder` action method code needs the Id, you need to pass it from client side. You should have other security check in your action method to make sure that only the user who has sufficient authorization is performing the operation.

Comment: You could either use a different identifier for each order other than id, or you could encrypt your id values and pass them to the view as encrypted id values, then decrypt server side, if you can't decrypt successfully you know it was tampered with

Comment: You can use ViewModel where you store the data that needed from the view.

Comment: The user can always edit anything on the client-side. It's your responsibility to ensure that, when the edit is received on the server-side, that it's data that the user is entitled to edit.

Comment: It must be included in the request (otherwise you will not what the value is in the post method), but you can add it as a route value rather than adding a hidden input. And it should not be an issue because you handle security on the serer, not the client (i.e. you check that the current user has the permission to edit the record with that ID)

Comment: I have permissions
but what if you have global system and you want to edit the data? i don't want to add new records to encrypt the field, do you think that Microsoft have something like the AntiForgeryTokens to protect the primary key of the model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to put the primary key in a hidden field. Your application should not be vulnerable as long as you have proper validation in place. If a user changes the value of the hidden field, your validation should be making sure that the current user should have access to that record.

Comment: So you say that i have to have a record in database for record owner?
what if you have a kind of flow system, then the record have more than one person that make changes on it

Comment: The record doesn't have to have an owner. It has to have a primary key which is simply a unique identifier for that record in the database. You can allow more than one person to make changes to a given record if you want to.